# How to append a div with script tag into an li tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

We have a `<ul>` with many `<li>` tags that is used for a menu links. How can we append the following code to the end of the `<ul>`?

Problem:

My current code is not adding even the `<div>` tag.

Goal:
Always append the `<li><div><script></script></div></li>` as the very last item of the `<ul class="menu" id="footer-menu">` by first creating the `<script>` tag and then appending it to the newly created `<div>` tag and then finally appending it to the end of the `<ul>` tag.

Current output:

```
<ul class="menu" id="footer-menu">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Desired output:

```
<ul class="menu" id="footer-menu">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li><div id='somevalue'><script async="async" crossorigin type="text/javascript" src="some-src"></script></div></li>
</ul>
```

```js
(function() {
  var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
  scriptTag.type="text/javascript";
  scriptTag.async=true;
  scriptTag.crossOrigin=true;
  scriptTag.src="some-source";
  
  var divTag = document.createElement('div');
  divTag.id='somevalue';
  divTag.append(scriptTag);
  var ulList = document.getElementById('footer-menu');
  ulList.append(divTag);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu" id="footer-menu">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How will you decide which element to append?

Comment: @Caveman the goal is to append the `<li><div><script></script></div></li>` to the very end of the `<ul>` all the time. We would always append to the end of the `<ul class="menu" id="footer-menu">` element. If you look at my code closely, you will see that i attempt to append the `<script>` tag to the `<div>` tag and then the `<div> to the <ul> tag.

Comment: I think this is the answer you're looking for. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the anonymous function, use this instead:

```js
(function() {
  var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
  scriptTag.type="text/javascript";
  scriptTag.async=true;
  scriptTag.crossOrigin=true;
  scriptTag.src="some-source";
  
  var divTag = document.createElement('div');
  divTag.id='somevalue';
  divTag.append(scriptTag);
  
  var liTag = document.createElement('li');
  liTag.append(divTag);
  
  var ulList = document.getElementById('footer-menu');
  ulList.append(liTag);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu" id="footer-menu">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: adding the `()` did the trick. wow, can't believe i missed that.

Comment: @usernameabc Yes, that was your issue. Your function's contents were correct (aside from the fact that you were not appending the "div" to a "li" element and appending that to the "ul"), but you were not calling the function.

Comment: your solution resolved my issue but i found another bug. I marked this as resolved and moved my other question to a separate post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50420726/how-to-add-just-crossorigin-to-script-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Use the lastChild property of the ul.

Try changing the last line to:

`ulList.lastChild.append(divTag);`

Comment: i get `{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: ulList.lastChild.append is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 35,
  "colno": 18
}` error message

Comment: That's most likely an "undefined" exception which can happen when the ul is empty.

Comment: i tried it again by adding more `<li>` to the `<ul>`, but it did not give me what i wanted, basically got my original problem.

Comment: append will add element at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution will append a `div` with a `script` tag into the desired `li` tag:

```
$("#footer-menu li").last().append('<div id="somevalue"><script async="async" crossorigin type="text/javascript" src="some-src"></script></div>');
```